# Filter Data completely user defined r - multiple columns and filters

Tags: r, function, filtering, user-input

I am attempting to create a function that will allow a user to define an infinite number of columns and apply matching filters to those columns.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=round(runif(10)), c=round(runif(10)))
|a| b|c|
|1| 1|1|
|2| 0|0|
|3| 0|1|
|4| 1|0|
|5| 1|0|
|6| 1|0|
|7| 1|1|
|8| 1|1|
|9| 1|0|
|10|1|1|
```

I would like the user to be able to filter the data based off either column, and apply different filters to each column. I know the following does not work. But this would be the general idea.

```
test <- function(df, fCol, fParam){
    df %>% filter(fCol[1] %in% fParam[1] | fCol[2] %in% fParam[2])
}
test(df, c("b","c"),c(1,0)
# Which I would want it to return
|a|b|c|
|4|1|0|
|5|1|0|
|6|1|0|
|9|1|0|
```

The issue that I run into is that I won't know how many columns the user will want to filter, nor will I know the column names.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Please ask questions if you have them. I tried my best to give a reprex.

Comment: Looks like you will need to get the hang of `tidyeval` and quoting and unquoting arguments to a function. This will allow the user to pass vectors of column names and filter variables via your function. See: https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html for a starting point - I can send you further links on tidyeval if you are stuck.

Comment: Is it fair to say the user must be constrained to supply vectors of equal length for fCol and fParam (seems like an essential constraint but just checking)?

Comment: Yes, the length of fCol would have to be equal to fParam. There probably is a way to remove this constraint but I currently believe that simply creating a function of this nature is challenging enough, to begin with. Also, I have worked a great deal with tidyeval, and understand its workings. My issue is more with trying to determine a way to map the two parameters together and pass it into filter. I have tried using map2 and pmap but wasn't able to figure out a way that would work

Comment: ok I'm working on something for you - good to understand the issue is more with map than with tidyeval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should satisfy what you want

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
test <- function(df,
                 fCol,
                 fParam,
                 match_type = "any")
   {
  if(!is.element(match_type, c("any","all"))|length(match_type)!=1){
    stop()
  }
  df <- df %>% ungroup() %>%
    mutate(..id..=1:n())
  meta <- data.frame(fCol=fCol,fParam=fParam)
  logi <- df %>%
    select("..id..",fCol) %>%
    gather(key = "key", value = "value", -..id..) %>%
    left_join(., y = meta, by = c("key"="fCol")) %>%
    mutate(match = value==fParam) %>%
    select(-key,-value, -fParam) %>%
    group_by_at(setdiff(names(.),"match")) %>%
    summarise(match = ifelse(match_type%in%"any",any(match), all(match)))
  df2 <- left_join(df, logi, by = intersect(colnames(df),colnames(logi))) %>%
    filter(match)%>%
    select(-match, -..id..)
  return(df2)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=round(runif(10)), c=round(runif(10)))
df
#    a b c
#1   1 0 1
#2   2 1 0
#3   3 0 0
#4   4 0 1
#5   5 0 1
#6   6 0 1
#7   7 1 0
#8   8 1 1
#9   9 1 0
#10 10 1 0

#use "any" to do an | match
test(df, c("b","c"),c(1,0), match_type = "any")
#   a b c
#1  2 1 0
#2  3 0 0
#3  7 1 0
#4  8 1 1
#5  9 1 0
#6 10 1 0

#use "all" to do an & match
test(df, c("b","c"),c(1,0), match_type = "all")
#   a b c
#1  2 1 0
#2  7 1 0
#3  9 1 0
#4 10 1 0
```

You can also specify the same colname for `fCol` multiple times if you want to match multiple values

```
test(df, c("b","b"),c(1,0)) #matches everything but you get the point
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would make one small edit, and add stringsAsFactors = FALSE when creating the meta dataframe. This removes the warning message that gets created. But other than that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> (my original response):
>
> *I am not sure this quite gives you the process you
>   want, but here's my best attempt before running out of
>   patience!!!* :-)
>
> *I am sure there is a good way to make this an AND filter not an OR but I
>   can't quite get there myself. (Maybe a combination of `map_dfc` and
>   `inner_join`?)*

**Edit: got there in the end! Improved code below (original code deleted).**

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tibble))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))

my_df <- tibble(
  a=1:10,
  b=round(runif(10)),
  c=round(runif(10))
  )
my_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        a     b     c
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0
#>  2     2     1     0
#>  3     3     0     1
#>  4     4     0     0
#>  5     5     1     1
#>  6     6     0     1
#>  7     7     0     0
#>  8     8     0     1
#>  9     9     1     0
#> 10    10     1     0

col_names <- c("b", "c")
tests <- c(1, 0)

#  option 1: with a named function:

make_test_frame <- function(col_name, test) {
  tibble({{col_name}} := test)
}

my_df1 <- map2_dfc(col_names, tests, make_test_frame) %>% 
  inner_join(x = my_df)
#> Joining, by = c("b", "c")
my_df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     0
#> 2     2     1     0
#> 3     9     1     0
#> 4    10     1     0

# 2. or with an anonymous function:

my_df1 <- map2_dfc(
  col_names, tests,
  function(col_name, test) {
    tibble({{col_name}} := test)
  }
) %>% 
  inner_join(x = my_df)
#> Joining, by = c("b", "c")
my_df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     0
#> 2     2     1     0
#> 3     9     1     0
#> 4    10     1     0

# 3. or as one big, hairy function:

filter_df <- function(df, col_names, tests) {
  map2_dfc(
    col_names, tests,
    function(col_name, test) {
      tibble({{col_name}} := test)
    }
  ) %>% 
    inner_join(x = df)
}

my_df1 <- filter_df(my_df, col_names = c("b", "c"), tests = c(1, 0))
#> Joining, by = c("b", "c")
my_df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     0
#> 2     2     1     0
#> 3     9     1     0
#> 4    10     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>